# Can I check whether it is correct about restriction of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I've not learned about restriction of a function. However, the solution in the web-site is using the restriction of a function. Thus, I read its definition in the wikipedia. However, I do not sure that the following is correct.

For an open set $G\in\mathbb{R^1}$, a function $f:\mathbb{R^n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R^1}$, and a sequence of sets $\left\{F_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$,
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left.f\right|_{F_n}^{-1}(G) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(f^{-1}(G) \cap F_n\right)
$$

Is the equality true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

$$
f|_X^{-1}(G)=\{x\in X:\ f(x)\in G\}=f^{-1}(G)\cap X.
$$